# Data extraction from XML with Python

Tags: python, xml

I am struggling with the extraction of specific data from XML. Unfortunately, I have no experience with programming at all. For a whole week, I was trying to solve it on my own without much success.

My XML file is the output of a natural language processing software.

It has the following structure: it gives the confidence of the recognition, the end time of the word's verbalisation, the phonological transcription, the start time and after that the word. I would like to extract the start/end time of certain words. E.g.  **end="3249555"   start="3249105"  Verfahren** (the processed text is in German).

I know that the ElemetTree is a package that reads the XML file. 
I have tried out the following code but without success

[image]

and an excerpt from the XML file

[image]

I would really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Adding actual code instead of images helps others run/test your code in order to help solve your problem.

Comment: In general, if you are giving code examples, please paste the actual code rather than screenshots.

Comment: Please post your code in the question rather than a picture of your code. In the case of the error you show in your screenshot, you never defined the vairable "word". Did you mean to write `for Verfharen in e:`, because e is the variable you assigned your element search to?

Comment: I would like to add the actual script, but I do not how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
root.findAll('//*[text()="Verfahren"])
```

Then find methods to get *attributes*